# "if source == <IP> unless destination == IP"?

Tags: iptables

I am trying to set up a pihole as a domain name resolver on my router running OpenWrt.

Currently I am running this iptables-script to force every device in my network to use my (pihole-)dns server (as far as possible at least):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.178.11 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.11:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.178.11 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.11:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.178.11 -p tcp --dport 853 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.11:853
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.178.11 -p udp --dport 853 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.11:853
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.178.11 -p tcp --dport 5353 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.11:5353
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s 192.168.178.11 -p udp --dport 5353 -j DNAT --to 192.168.178.11:5353
```

I recently had on outtage on machine `192.168.178.11` that made me rethink my setup since when the machine went down my whole network couldn't resolve dns requests. I'd like to run a similar set of iptables-rules that forward all dns requests to my pihole but only if the destination isn't `169.239.202.202`, which is an OpenNic dns server.

The idea is to hand out `169.239.202.202` as a second dns server and to not reroute port 53/853/5353 requests to my pihole if that server is the destination. Basically a "if destination port is 53 and source is not pihole forward request to pihole, but **only** if the destination isn't `169.239.202.20`"

Is that possible with iptables?

Comment: Isn't it the same as `if destination port is 53 and source is not pihole and destination isn't 169.239.202.20`? Nothing stops you from having a (negated) `-d` additionally.

Comment: Thanks, @TomYan, that was exactly the help I needed. Works as expected. If you turn this into an answer I'll accept it.